# Does keytool use some data erasure procedure to delete an entry internally?

Tags: java, keytool

Do they use some secure data erasure procedure like Bruce Schneier's algorithm, Peter Gutmann's Algorithm or other pattern?

Comment: What keystore implmentation? keytool just delegates entry deletion to `KeyStoreSpi#engineDeleteEntry(...)`

Comment: I was thinking about JKS. Is this (or should it be) part of the specification?

Comment: I cannot find something special in the source code (https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/19fb8f93c59dfd791f62d41f332db9e306bc1422/src/java.base/share/classes/java/security/KeyStore.java#L1246)

Comment: Well, that's not the place where erasure would happen.  It would happen in the SPI implementation code.

Comment: I'm curious as to what security benefit you think that would provide inside an encrypted container?

Comment: @HopeyOne, you are totally right. I forgot about the fact that the keystore is encrypted. It doesn't seem that data erasure procedures are relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, that's not where any erasure code would be.  It would actually be in (or around) the `com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore` class.  That is the built-in implementation of the `KeyStoreSpi` used by keytool, etcetera.

But looking at those, I think that the answer is No.

In fact, the `engineDeleteEntry` method is just manipulating an in-memory copy of the keystore.  There are separate methods for loading and storing the in-memory keystore.  These just operate on `InputStream` and `OutputStream` ... and don't do anything special to erase the previous copy of the file.

That leaves us with `keytool` itself as a place where erasure could possibly happen happen.  And it doesn't.  It simply opens a `FileOutputStream` and writes the new (encrypted) keystore contents to the output file.

---

But as others have noted, there is little value in erasing the old copy of the file ... given that a keystore stored in an encrypted form.

Comment: I think the last part, that there is no value of erasing old copies is the most important one. As I replied to @HopeyOne as well, I forgot about the fact that the keystore is encrypted. It doesn't seem that data erasure procedures are relevant here. Thank you guys!